# Android - How to Marquee in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to achieve marquee in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` title.

My layout structure is :

```
<AppBarLayout>
    <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <ImageView/> // Background
        <MarqueeToolbar/>
    </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</AppBarLayout>
```

Where `MarqueeToolbar` is :

```
public class MarqueeToolbar extends Toolbar {

    TextView title;

    public MarqueeToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MarqueeToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MarqueeToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        if (!reflected) {
            reflected = reflectTitle();
        }
        super.setTitle(title);
        selectTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int resId) {
        if (!reflected) {
            reflected = reflectTitle();
        }
        super.setTitle(resId);
        selectTitle();
    }

    boolean reflected = false;
    private boolean reflectTitle() {
        try {
            Field field = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            title = (TextView) field.get(this);
            title.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            title.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
            title.setFocusable(true);
            title.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            title.canScrollHorizontally(1);
            title.setSingleLine();
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void selectTitle() {
        if (title != null)
            title.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Tried using that `MarqueeToolbar` which I copied from somewhere in SO.

Then I delved a bit into `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and found out that it uses `CollapsingTextHelper` in its `onLayout` to draw the text, not the `Toolbar`. `Toolbar` is used to get the title, so whatever I do to change the `Toolbar` properties seems useless.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

...
// Finally, set our minimum height to enable proper AppBarLayout collapsing
if (mToolbar != null) {
    if (mCollapsingTitleEnabled && TextUtils.isEmpty(mCollapsingTextHelper.getText())) {
        // If we do not currently have a title, try and grab it from the Toolbar
        mCollapsingTextHelper.setText(mToolbar.getTitle());
    }
    if (mToolbarDirectChild == null || mToolbarDirectChild == this) {
        setMinimumHeight(getHeightWithMargins(mToolbar));
    } else {
        setMinimumHeight(getHeightWithMargins(mToolbarDirectChild));
    }
}
updateScrimVisibility();
```

}

I tried extending `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but I am stuck as the part where I want to change is in `onLayout` and the `CollapsingTextHelper` is a restricted `android.support` class.

The part where text is drawn in `CollapsingTextHelper` seems to be at

```
private void calculateUsingTextSize(final float textSize) {

    ...
    final CharSequence title = TextUtils.ellipsize(mText, mTextPaint,
            availableWidth, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    if (!TextUtils.equals(title, mTextToDraw)) {
        mTextToDraw = title;
        mIsRtl = calculateIsRtl(mTextToDraw);
    }
    }
```

What should I do to achieve the marquee with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: It would work, if I don't need the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.. I tried doing that, and I even retried it just now just in case I missed something yesterday, and it failed. I'll update my question to show that the text doesn't seem to be drawn on the toolbar to narrow it down

Comment: Hmm, guess I'll have to look into `CollapsingToolbarLayout` again. It's been a while.

Comment: Yup, I've never tried extending and changing `CTL`, I've only tried extending and changing views using texts for custom fonts.. Btw I meant it failed to collapse together with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, it behaves as normal toolbar, no collapse animation, not failed to achieve the marquee animation, I think I was ambiguous there

Comment: Right, yeah. I forgot how the `Toolbar` behaves there. I'm thinking it's going to be easier to put your marquee `TextView` in the layout separately, and anchor it to the bottom of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Trying to do this with the `CollapsingTextHelper` is going to be too unwieldy, methinks.

Comment: Ah that's a good way to overcome the current situation.. I shall make the  `TextView` to autoresize and anchor it down there to simulate the behavior, be right back

Comment: Ack, I forgot that I have a `setHomeAsUp`, and I need to  adjust the margins and such, as `AppBarLayout` has to be the direct descendant of `CoordinatorLayout` AFAIK, I can't just wrap them up in a `ConstraintLayout`. Hmm, should I just abandon the `CollapsingToolbar` for now?

Comment: Well, I think you could put the `TextView` directly in the `CoordinatorLayout`, anchor it to the bottom of the `AppBarLayout`, and set a left margin on it. I'll whip up a little test project here in a minute, to see if we can do this somewhat elegantly.

Comment: I have `setHomeAsUp` enabled, so, anchoring it just like that won't really work.. Gotta have to add left margin too, but it's really hacky :/

Comment: Yeesh, yeah, this is kind of a pain. Maybe it would be easier to add a marquee functionality to `CollapsingTextHelper`. Lemme look into that.

Comment: @MikeM. That would be awesome! But it'd be hard cz there will be red lint everywhere in the custom helper as they're only to be used in google support package.. Might need to clone the whole support package! LOL

Comment: Actually, that's probably not gonna be great, either. Unless we do fork the whole kit, all we could do is shift the text one character at a time, rather than smoothly scroll. I'm back to thinking the `TextView` directly in the `CoordinatorLayout` is the way to go, but it'd take a custom `Behavior` to mimic the motion that `CollapsingTextHelper` does.

Comment: Haha of course it won't be great, it'll be really annoying, so much work just for a marquee. Yeah directly down there and anchoring it to the `CollapsingToolbar` with a fixed height would be feasible, but hacky.. Custom behavior? Just like `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` is it?

Comment: Yeah, but we'd have to create our own, which isn't too difficult, and I've got something that's almost there already, but I can't get the _!#$@_ `TextView` to marquee at all.

Comment: Oop, never mind. Got it. Lemme clean up my code, and I'll link you an example to test. It'll be a little bit, though.

Comment: OK, sorry that took so long. It was a little more involved than I'd originally figured. Anyhoo, I think I covered everything you need to know in order to test this, and see if it'll work for you. Lemme know if you've any trouble getting it running. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DSngX9Vr_ZAQAgf22fsgyqZkS4WTtrnf/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I should mention that you'll eventually need to remove/disable the title on the `Toolbar` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. In fact, I'm not even sure we still need the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` anymore, but I didn't get a chance to test anything past getting the custom `Behavior` working. For now, you can just leave your original setup as is. The marquee `TextView` will be overlaid over everything else, and you'll be able to see if things line up adequately. If this is gonna work for you, I'll continue refining this approach.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on a weekend retreat, I'll check it out right now as I've just got back to office!

Comment: I am unable to see the title, even if I set the elevation as high as 32dp, and android:elevation is for api 21 and above right? I have lowest API at 17 :( Here's my current layout https://drive.google.com/open?id=12Gtrp0-1Eeo1A0nYihLGylZ4_bQKS9j_

Comment: Move the `TextView` to be the very last thing inside the `CoordinatorLayout`. You might also wanna test that custom `TextView` on its own, if you haven't, to make sure it's working by itself.

Comment: It still doesn't work, hmm am I missing something here? I did what you written, it's very clear, and it's almost impossible to miss anything there lol.. Check out the CustomFontTextView I wrote in the Drive, I have a habit of making a customview for everything that can have text on it, been that way since my last huge project where I had to change every font to a custom one right in the middle of the project. Had to move timeline by 2 days to refactor everything lol

Comment: Dunno. I'm about ready to crash, so I'm not very astute, at the moment. Check your logs to make sure you're not getting an Exception in the `catch` in `ToolbarTitleBehavior`. I'm not sure what your `Toolbar` XML or complete code setup looks like, but if you're not setting the `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar`, you should set a non-empty `app:title` attribute on it, at least for testing. `ToolbarTitleBehavior` currently depends on the `Toolbar`'s internal title `TextView`, which won't exist unless it's explicitly set somehow. We can change that later.

Comment: Whoa, easy there, take a break, have a KitKat! I do set it as support `ActionBar`, and I always do that, somehow it's been a habit too, and I needed the support library, been very nice to me! Currently checking it out, by the code itself, it should show, showing layout bounds shows the `TextView`, but no text, be back when I find anything

Comment: Here's my whole basic test project (zip file): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PGVvS-zQNeLJ9MJAlc-87hoD4AX6Hish/view?usp=drivesdk. If you can't get things working in your current setup, you might wanna try with that, since it's just the bare essentials.

Comment: It's working well, really well, until I add `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");` it breaks, I thought it was because I have a `BottomSheet`, but I tried adding `BottomSheet` to yours, it still work, but when I set title to "", it fails

Comment: But if I set title to " ", it works! Hahaha.. There's a problem though, how to set the collapsed text size? For expanded size, I can set it directly on the `TextView`, what about the collapsed version?

Comment: Yeah, `Toolbar` creates the title `TextView` dynamically, and when it doesn't have a title to display, there's no `TextView` there. We can remove the dependency on that title `TextView`, though, either by mimicking what `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does, or by putting a dummy, empty `TextView` in the `Toolbar` (which, I think, is basically what `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does, anyway). I'd originally just grabbed the title `TextView` because it gets set up automatically with the right text size, position, etc. I didn't get around to doing to, but you got should be able to fix it pretty easily.

Comment: Remove the reflection stuff, add a `<TextView>` in the `<Toolbar>` with `layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"` and `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"`, change the `toolbar` `attr` to point to that `TextView`, then get `titleView` in the code with `cl.findViewById()` with that `attr` value.

Comment: The collapsed text size currently comes from the `Toolbar`'s title `TextView`'s text size. If you make the changes like I just described, you could specify a `textSize` on the dummy `TextView`. Anyhoo, I have to get some sleep right now, but I can put all this together first thing tomorrow, which is only like 5 hours from now.

Comment: Whoa thanks Mike! I'm gonna start doing what you just said, I think I can do it right now. Thanks for the insight of how `CollapsingToolbarLayout` works, I didn't know that it has a dummy empty `TextView`, it makes sense tho. Good night, and thanks again!

Comment: Well, I got called into work for a minor catastrophe, so I didn't get to this until now. Anyhoo, here's a project with the changes I mentioned: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LVTnd0ymE1WhHP8FIhX1peZMBPzeJty0/view?usp=drivesdk. I renamed the `attr` and some variables in the `Behavior`, but everything else is just as I commented. Notice that the dummy `<TextView>` has a `textSize` set, like you were asking about. The `TextAppearance` will make it the standard title size, by default, but you can specify whatever you want there.

Comment: Woah, I hope that minor catastrophe doesn't have any lasting effect! I didn't manage to make it yesterday, I am kinda new in this custom attr thingy, so I couldn't understand some part of it.. But now after reading your code, I get it, basically make a dummy `TextView`, place it in `Toolbar` so that the title follow that `TextView` size. Testing it now.. Oh and what about any menu in the right? A hacky solution would be to specify each width and add them up for sizing, or set `TextView` by percentage, hmm.. Got any insight on this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A regular options menu still works with this.

Comment: Umm I mean, it'll overlap the options menu right? Haven't tried tho, but I think it would.. Let me try whipping it up

Comment: Oh, you mean your marquee title is full-width?

Comment: Yes! Full width, from the `homeAsUp` part to whatever option menu there, currently I have one option menu and yes it is blocking the view in my actual project, I'm currently looking for a dynamic way of getting option menu width and `homeAsUp` width.. Hope there's a way

Comment: Yeah, we should be able to make the dummy `<TextView>`'s `layout_width` `match_parent`, then adjust our marquee `TextView`'s width to be the same as the dummy. The dummy `TextView` will only be as wide as the leftover space after the nav button and the menu items. I'll test it now.

Comment: You're right, if the simulated `TV` can follow the dummy `TV`'s size, then it would work! But, there's a width scaling right? Would that be a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166723/discussion-between-mike-m-and-kevin-murvie).

Comment: OK, I was curious as to how the fading edge was handled, anyway, so here's one last go at this, using the custom `TextView` I mentioned in chat: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1przijvqNVf3vaa8aPg_2B5lIPeeC67cK/view?usp=drivesdk. It's full-width in the expanded state (minus whatever margins you set), maintains the fading edge on both sides, and shrinks to the available space in the `Toolbar`, accounting for the nav button and any number of menu items.

Comment: Oh wow, I just got back to work and written something in the chat, and now I see you commented lol, let me try it in my test project!

Comment: You sir, deserve multiple upvotes, post it as an aswer and I shall like it million times over if possible!

Comment: Hey, there. Sure, I'll put together an answer, eventually. I still wanna clean up the code a little more, and I also wanna get the clipping to work in the other direction. That is, currently, if the scaled-down title ends up being shorter than the available width in the `Toolbar`, it just leaves a lot of blank space. This happens when the collapsed text size is smaller than the expanded; e.g., if you were to remove the `textSize` attribute. I want to get it to grow to fill that space, so that the answer will be more widely applicable. It might be a day or so, but I'll get one posted. :-)

Comment: Whoa thanks! I can learn a lot from your answer! Ohhh I get it, just like yesterday, but now in the vertical department, and make it more dynamic is it? No worries! The link you provided, as unclean as you claims it to be, is really good, and I can start reading from there, phew, at last, after several weeks of going in and out of this `Marquee` part. I should've asked for help long ago :')